# Creating a vertically-oriented "title" for a list environment

Tags: lists

In MS Word, it is possible to create a list environment with a vertically-oriented "title" of the following sort:

[image]

Here the title is "Responsibilities." I would like to know whether it is possible to do a similar thing in LaTeX. I have seen some commands and packages for rotating text in-line and in other places, but I haven't found any package or hack to set off the oriented text to the side of the list environment.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, though probably not in a fully automatic way. Could you post some compilable short code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I provide the `litemize` environment, which produces the same list indent as `itemize`.

I achieve it by placing the list in a `\vcenter`ed `\vbox`.  Because the list is now vertically centered, I can pre-add the leading label as a lapped box rotated 90 degrees about its center.

Of course, because the list is in a box, it will not break across pages.  But with it leading label that centers across the list, you would not want it to break across pages, anyhow.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum}
\newenvironment{litemize}[1]
{\noindent\makebox[0pt][l]{%
  \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\bfseries #1}}$\vcenter\bgroup\vbox\bgroup\begin{itemize}}
{\end{itemize}\egroup\egroup$}
\begin{document}
\begin{litemize}{Test}
\item blah
\item blah
\item blah
\item blah
\end{litemize}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{litemize}{Responsibilities}
\item blah
\item blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
\item blah
\item blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
\item blah
\item blah
\end{litemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]